# How to write an input pipeline that preprocess multiple examples at each step in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

I have tfrecords and each example consists of an image and a feature vector, but without labels. Labels are extracted based current feature vector and feature vector of next step. I would like to know if there is a good way to write an input pipeline to do this?

For most of the tutorials they only apply a map function to an example each time. But what I want to do is to apply a map function to two sequential examples.

Hope I have made myself clear and looking for an answer!